# Hector Cassandra Connectivity Error

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am trying to connect to a local cassandra instance through a java client powered by Hector. I attempt to read rows after trying to connect. The code snippet is as follows

Cluster myCluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test" , "localhost:9160");

KeyspaceDefinition keySpaceDef = myCluster.describeKeyspace("testkeyspace");

.....

However the connectivity fails with this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_OPERATIONS_IN_MILLIONS
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.(ThriftCfDef.java:65)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.fromThriftList(ThriftCfDef.java:144)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftKsDef.(ThriftKsDef.java:34)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:192)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:187)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:101)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:232)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:201)

I have cassandra, thrift as dependencies in my pom.xml. Any clues as to what could be wrong?

Comment: What versions of C* and Hector are you using?

Comment: I am marking this as resolved. The problem was I had conflicting versions of apache thrift